# Oracle Vendor Code 17002 Large Select Columns

Tags: oracle

When executing a select that returns a large amount of columns over several tables the error "Vendor code 17002" is received. The query only returns one result. When the number of columns returned is less than 635, the query works. When another column is added the error is seen.

The following was seen in a dump file:

```
Exception [type: ACCESS_VIOLATION, UNABLE_TO_READ] [ADDR:0x45] [PC:0x35797B4, _kkqstcrf()+1342]
DDE: Problem Key 'ORA 7445 [kkqstcrf()+1342]' was flood controlled (0x6) (incident: 10825)
ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [kkqstcrf()+1342] [ACCESS_VIOLATION] [ADDR:0x45] [PC:0x35797B4] [UNABLE_TO_READ] []
Dump file c:\app\7609179\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_s001_9928.trc
Thu Feb 07 15:10:56 2013
ORACLE V11.2.0.1.0 - Production vsnsta=0
vsnsql=16 vsnxtr=3
Dumping diagnostics for abrupt exit from ksedmp
```

Windows 7, Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 Enterprise Edition, SQL Developer, Same result from Java Application.

Answer (score 1):

ORA-07445 is a generic error which Oracle uses to signal unexpected behaviour in the OS i.e. a bug.

There should be some additional information in that trace file:

```
c:\app\7609179\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_s001_9928.trc
```

Have you looked in it?

Unfortunately the nature of ORA-07445 means that the solution underlying problem is usually due to the specific combination of platform, OS and database versions.  Oracle have published  some advice on diagnosis but most routes lead to calling Oracle Support.  [Find out more](https://blogs.oracle.com/db/entry/ora-7445_troubleshooting).

At least you know the immediate cause.  So if you don't have a Support contract there is a workaround: change you application so you don't have to select that 635th column.  That is an awful lot of columns to have in a single query.

There isn't an actual limit to the  number of columns permitted in a query's projection but it's possible that the total length of the statement exceeds the limit. This limit varies according to several factors and [isn't ispecified in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/limits003.htm#i288032).  How long (how many chars) is the statement with and with out that pesky additional column?  perhaps shortening some column names will do the trick.